# Como mudar o tipo de letra em um gráfico no R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Quero usar usar a fonte *Times New Roman* no gráfico, mas o *R/Rstudio* retorna uma mensagem de erro dizendo não encontra-la. Obviamente a fonte está em algum lugar pois utilizo no *MS Word*, por exemplo.

A um tempo atrás o comando abaixo funcionava normalmente e parou de funcionar em algum momento depois de alguma atualização que não sei se foi do *Windows*, do *R*, do *Rstudio* ou do *ggplot2*.

```r
# Exemplo reproduzível a partir de um banco de dados 
# que já vem incluso com o ggplot2:

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "Diamantes: Quilates X Preço") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"))

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database
```

[image: Gráfico price X carac]

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  Portuguese_Brazil.1252      
#>  tz       America/Sao_Paulo           
#>  date     2017-12-03
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version date       source                         
#>  backports    1.1.1   2017-09-25 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
#>  base       * 3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  colorspace   1.3-2   2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  compiler     3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  datasets   * 3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  devtools     1.13.4  2017-11-09 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
#>  digest       0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  evaluate     0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  ggplot2    * 2.2.1   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  graphics   * 3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  grDevices  * 3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  grid         3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  gtable       0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  htmltools    0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  knitr        1.17    2017-08-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
#>  labeling     0.3     2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
#>  magrittr     1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  memoise      1.1.0   2017-12-01 Github (hadley/memoise@d63ae9c)
#>  methods    * 3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  munsell      0.4.3   2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  plyr         1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  Rcpp         0.12.14 2017-11-23 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
#>  rlang        0.1.4   2017-11-05 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
#>  rmarkdown    1.8     2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
#>  rprojroot    1.2     2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  scales       0.5.0   2017-08-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
#>  stats      * 3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  stringi      1.1.6   2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
#>  stringr      1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
#>  tibble       1.3.4   2017-08-22 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
#>  tools        3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  utils      * 3.4.3   2017-11-30 local                          
#>  withr        2.1.0   2017-11-01 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                 
#>  yaml         2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
windowsFonts(Times=windowsFont("Times New Roman"))

library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "Diamantes: Quilates X Preço") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Times"))
```

**EDITADO**:

Minha compreensão (talvez errônea) do problema:

Cada dispositivo gráfico há seu próprio banco de fontes disponível. Essas fontes podem ser limitadas (por isso a utilidade de pacotes com fontes extras (p.e. `extrafont`), além de diferentes nomes dependendo do dispositivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A Função `windowsFonts` serve para "traduzir" do dispositivo gráfico (p.e. `R`) ao sistema Windows.

Comment: Sua resposta entrou para a lista de **Publicações de baixa qualidade**, poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/260195/edit) e dar um breve explicação sobre sua reposta ?

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado Willian! Você saberia dizer qual o problema no código anterior? Também gostaria de saber se tem como chamar a fonte diretamente, sem precisar usar um "apelido" (no caso, Times).

Comment: @Enoch adicionei uma possível explicação ao problema, mas sujeito à discussão. Quando ao utilizar a fonte diretamente, não achei nenhuma solução.